# Aunque ponga números divisores siempre me muestra que no son divisores

Tags: c++

Tengo una consulta respecto a que mi código, no funciona, y aunque ponga números divisores siempre me muestra que no son divisores.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void){
    
    int ND,N1,N2,N3,N4;
    cout<<"INGRESE NUMERO D"<<endl;
    cin>>ND;
    cout<<"INGRESE EL PRIMER NUMERO"<<endl;
    cin>>N1;
    cout<<"INGRESE EL SEGUNDO NUMERO"<<endl;
    cin>>N2;
    cout<<"INGRESE EL TERCER NUMERO"<<endl;
    cin>>N3;
    cout<<"INGRESE EL CUARTO NUMERO"<<endl;
    cin>>N4;
    
    if ((N1 % ND == 0) && (N2 % ND == 0) && (N3 % ND == 0) && (N4 % ND == 0)){
    cout<<"ES DIVISOR DE LOS CUATRO NUMEROS"<<ND<<endl;
}
else

    {
        cout<<"NO SON DIVISORES DE "<<ND<<endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Podes agregar un ejemplo de la entrada y la salida?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Acabo de comprobar tu código en un editor online, porque de primeras me parecía que el código que habías mostrado era correcto, y así es; el código funciona de forma correcta. Tu problema puede ser que tu código sólo devuelve true en el `if` si los 4 números son divisores. En cambio, con que uno no lo sea, ya devuelve el `else`. Si quieres comprobar cuántos son divisores, en el `if`comprueba que al menos, 1, sea divisor (cambia `&&` por `||`) y, dentro del if, compruebas uno a uno con varios `if`s cuáles son divisores y lo vas mostrando por pantalla. El else lo puedes dejar.

Comment: Los mensajes de salida son contradictorios. En el primero indicas que `ND` es divisor común, en el segundo, en cambio, indicas que los 4 números **no son divisores** de `ND`. ¿En qué quedamos?

Comment: Si le pones por entrada `3 3 6 9 12` da el resultado correcto. Con que entrada de datos no te funciona?

Answer (score 0):

La guarda del if da true solo cuando ND es divisor de todos los demás, es decir que entrarías al else cuando ND no es divisor de alguno de N1, N2, N3 o N4. Sin embargo el mensaje que imprime el else da a entender que ninguno de los N es divisor de ND, cuando tendría que decir algo como: "ND no es divisor de todos N1, N2, N3 y N4"

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/380460)

Answer (score -1):

Te recomiendo que si necesitas ver los si el número ingresado sea divisor de los números ingresados, debes cambiar los operadores lógicos de la bifurcación de && (Y) a || (O) para así decir, *si es esto* **O** *esto otro* y no generalice la operación, aparte, formar dentro otras bifurcaciones para mostrar los resultados exactos.
Acabo de modificar tu código y así queda:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    
    int ND,N1,N2,N3,N4;
    cout<<"INGRESE NUMERO D"<<endl;
    cin>>ND;
    cout<<"INGRESE EL PRIMER NUMERO"<<endl;
    cin>>N1;
    cout<<"INGRESE EL SEGUNDO NUMERO"<<endl;
    cin>>N2;
    cout<<"INGRESE EL TERCER NUMERO"<<endl;
    cin>>N3;
    cout<<"INGRESE EL CUARTO NUMERO"<<endl;
    cin>>N4;
    
    if ((N1 % ND == 0) || (N2 % ND == 0) || (N3 % ND == 0) || (N4 % ND == 0)){
        if(N1 % ND == 0){
            cout<<ND<<" ES DIVISOR DE "<<N1<<endl;
        }
        if(N2 % ND == 0){
            cout<<ND<<" ES DIVISOR DE "<<N2<<endl;
        }
        if(N3 % ND == 0){
            cout<<ND<<" ES DIVISOR DE "<<N3<<endl;
        }
        if(N4 % ND == 0){
            cout<<ND<<" ES DIVISOR DE "<<N4<<endl;
        }
    }
    else{
        cout<<ND<<" NO ES DIVISOR DE LOS NUMEROS INGRESADOS."<<endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```